# Allow users who suggest an edit to choose that only the OP can approve/reject the edit

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

Some of the suggested edits suggest to change something in the code. Most of these edits get rejected as "invalid edit" or "radical change", but sometimes these edits are useful (and of course, sometimes they are not). For code edits, only the OP can decide whether the edit is useful or not, so I suggest that when someone suggests an edit, (s)he can choose whether everyone can approve/reject the edit, or only the OP. And if the edit is not approved/rejected within 14 days, the edit would go to the review queue:

[image: Suggested Edit: choose whether the OP should approve]

Comment: Sounds like a situation where you should just be posting a comment.

Comment: @Servy: But if you don't have 50 rep, then you can't.

Comment: Then you can't and you move on to a question that you *can* answer.

Comment: If implemented these should be non blocking edits. Their existance shouldn't block other edits for 14 days

Comment: I do not like this idea, but 14 days is too much anyway. Chances are a 2K+ user will have edited the question in the meantime if it really required modification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though I agree with the sentiment this can be used as a way of stopping a post from getting into shape.

If someone suggests an edit it blocks everyone else from suggesting an edit or editing themselves, if they have the privileges. This, in turn, means that fateful flaws with the post may not be cleaned up because of the "blocking" edit. This would be to the detriment of the site.

I honestly think a comment is better in this situation. It allows *everyone* no matter their privileges or whether they're logged-in or not to see why someone thought there was a problem. It then allows everyone to either state that the comment is (in)correct, enabling the community to deal with someone's question quicker (no matter whether the comment is on an answer or a question).

Answer (score 4):

Interesting idea, but don't think it's really needed. It will just make the queue grow and grow and new users will realize it's a golden path to have their edits approved without proper review process.

User who really want to improve a post by changing it radically will first have to gain 50 rep, then ask the post author for "permission" in a comment. If OP agree, that user can explain in the edit summary "OP agree, see comments".